# Gutenberg Block, getMedia() is undefined

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, undefined, block, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm trying to get the featured image of selected post, but I'm getting undefined when I try this:

```
const media = select('core').getMedia( FEATURED_IMAGE_ID );
console.log(media);
```

It turns to *undefined* when it's first try. If trigger the function for second time, it gives the json. I tried the async function but no luck.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [a similar issue in the `WordPress/gutenberg` repository](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/issues/14623#issuecomment-499445665):

> Since `getMedia` returns `undefined` when the data hasn't been retrieved yet, I suggest using the `withSelect` higher order component to do the `select('core').getMedia` part. Your component will re-render as soon as the data has been loaded and is available.

This was posted on June 6th 2019 and thus, a more succinct solution exists as per [this WordPress developer blog article](https://developer.wordpress.org/news/2022/12/13/application-state-managed-withdispatch-withselect-and-compose-101/):

> You should know that `useSelect` and `useDispatch` hooks are a more modern way of managing application state [than `withSelect` and `withDispatch`]

Thus, you could use `useSelect` as follows in your block:

```js
function MyBlockEdit( … ) {
  // …
  const media = useSelect(
    select => select( 'core' ).getMedia( FEATURED_IMAGE_ID ),
    [ FEATURED_IMAGE_ID ],
  );
  // …
```

This doesn't get around the root predicament that `getMedia` can be `undefined`, but this does seem to be the recommended way to handle the result. You should perhaps consider an empty state and/or a loading state in your block.

Comment: Yes, useSelect solved my issue. Thanks a lot! :)